# Ubuntu 23.10 gnome-shell v45.0/v45.1 crashes on restart

Tags: gnome-shell, crash, 23.10, mutter

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 23.04 to Ubuntu 23.10.

New problem that I didn't have before. When I restart gnome-shell with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, then <kbd>r</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it totally crashes gnome-shell, and shows a full `white screen of death` that indicates that some major error occurred, and that I must log out/in to continue. I've tried disabling all gnome-shell extensions without any improvement.

In limited testing so far, this only occurs if there's (any) application running. No applications running, and gnome-shell restart works fine. (I used `Firefox` and `terminal` to test with).

The problem also occurs in two different user accounts.

Any ideas why? Or where to start troubleshooting?

Comment: This was something that I didn't notice, because I am not using. However, I tested and saw exactly the same problem here: 23.04→23.10 upgraded Ubuntu with Gnome 45 on Xorg. Please, file a bug report and share it here, so that we can follow it also. Thanks.

Comment: I think this is your bug: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/7050   and  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/2040453   You can register and subscribe there to follow any progress.

Comment: gnome-shell 45.1 does not fix this problem. It looks to be a mutter problem.